# How can i query the dates between 2 columns with same username in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, date-arithmetic

I have a mysql table which has 'username', 'acctstarttime' and 'acctstoptime'(and an 'id') datetime columns. I need to get records that its acctstarttime or acctstoptime between other 'acctstarttime' and 'acctstoptime' records with same username. For example 'John' has 3 records.

| id | username | acctstarttime | acctstoptime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 29.12.2022 | 01.01.2023 |
| 2 | John | 30.12.2022 | 03.03.2023 |
| 3 | John | 12.12.2022 | 14.12.2022 |

Second rows acctstarttime is between first rows acctstarttime and acctstoptime and first rows acctstoptime is between second rows acctstarttime and acctstoptime. I want to query that 2 records.

I can do it with php but it takes about 3-4 days or more for 1 million records. I have very inefficient function.

How can i reduce this time in mysql or php(just speed up)?

I downloaded each record to different files based on username. I wrote this laravel code but it works too slow. It can be confusing.

```
    function findRecordsBetweenSameHours()
    {
        $directory = storage_path() . "/app/";
        $files = Storage::files('usernames');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $records =json_decode(file_get_contents($directory . $file), true);
            foreach ($records as $record) {
                $record["acctstarttime"] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $record["acctstarttime"]);
                $record["acctstoptime"] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $record["acctstoptime"]);
                foreach ($records as $record2) {
                    $record2["acctstarttime"] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $record2["acctstarttime"]);
                    $record2["acctstoptime"] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $record2["acctstoptime"]);
                    if (
                        ($record2["acctstoptime"]->between($record["acctstarttime"], $record["acctstoptime"], false)
                            || $record2["acctstarttime"]->between($record["acctstarttime"], $record["acctstoptime"], false)
                        )
                        && $record2["acctsessionid"] != $record["acctsessionid"]
                ) {
                        Storage::append('x.log',
                            $record["acctsessionid"] . " - " . $record2["acctsessionid"] . " - " . $record["username"]
                        );

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Storage::append('x.log',
            "finish"
        );
    }
```

Comment: Please, start using english in your function/method/variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write query like this

```
SELECT 
    t1.*
FROM
    table_name t1
        JOIN
    table_name t2 ON t1.username = t2.username
WHERE
    (t1.acctstarttime > t2.acctstarttime
        AND t1.acctstarttime < t2.acctstoptime)
        OR (t1.acctstoptime > t2.acctstarttime
        AND t1.acctstoptime < t2.acctstoptime);
```

Comment: That run much much more faster than other one. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you want records for which another record exists with the same user name and an overlapping period of time.

I would recommend `exists` and a few inequality conditions:

```
select *
from mytable t1
where exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t2
    where t1.id != t.id
      and t1.username = t2.username
      and t1.acctstarttime <= t2.acctstoptime 
      and t2.acctstarttime <= t1.acctstoptime
)
```

For each row, the subquery searches for an "overlapping" record of the same user, and filters in rows that match. The inequality conditions on the start and end time qualify the date range overlap.

An index on `(id, acctstarttime, acctstoptime)` might help performance.

Comment: Thank you... But i dont see where is t2 table named.

Comment: I removed '=' from 't1.acctstarttime <= t2.acctstoptime' and the following one. Because it sees itself and query all records again. I started to query and it looks loading(also @karan-darji 's query). I hope it will take just a few hour :). Thank you again btw.

Comment: @SezginSevinc: I see. If `id` is a unique key, then we can use it to avoid duplicates while still properly managing the date overlaps. I updated my answer accordingly, in case it helps.